# TCS/Math/Quantum Information Advice

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, computability, discrete-mathematics, quantum-computing

I am currently a high school 12th grader and am very interested in computer theory and pure mathematics. I also have a strong interest in astronomy and a desire to study quantum information.

However, physics and I really don't have a nice relationship. I am having trouble figuring out what major holds the topics I am interested in. Most university research on quantum information seems to be found in the physics/astronomy department, but I have also found joint computer theory/mathematics programs in their respective departments.

I don't want to be a physics major, but how can I fulfill my curiosity with quantum information? I am having great difficulty finding a university that offers undergraduate research in these fields.

Any tips on how to find research opportunities in these topics as an undergrad?

Comment: There's plenty of research being done on quantum information in CS departments. However, I'm not sure that many undergrad CS courses include the subject. You should probably choose an undergrad programme at a university where there are researchers working on quantum information and try to pick up the quantum stuff in your spare time, by talking to the researchers, going to their seminars and so on. Your undergrad program lasts three or four years so make sure it's something that interests you, and not just 3/4 years of slogging away to earn the right to do quantum information at grad school.

Comment: Overall, though, this site isn't well suited to giving careers advice, because any such advice is so specific to the single person asking. We don't know you well enough to give personal advice, and what works for you might not be interesting to anyone else.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Thank you for taking the time to respond. Yes, this will be my first and last "advice post" on here. I live in a very rural area so I did not have anyone I could reference who studies anything even remotely related to my interests. I could not seem to contact individuals who were actually in these fields on other "advice websites" so I thought I would gamble my chances once on stack exchange where I know a significant bubble of people with TCS experience exist.

Comment: If you pick up a little reputation by answering a couple of questions, you'll be able to ask for advice in [chat]. You only need 20 reputation, which is two upvotes to answers you write or four to questions.